# What Are All The 180 RPM Hand Cannons?

Tags: destiny-2

I just wanted to know all the 180 rpm hand cannons. Or at least, the ones attainable to through quests. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to be more specific, otherwise this question is far too broad to be answered. Do you also mean exotics? Do you consider white, green, blue, and purples to be included? Are you asking about kinetic hand cannons or energy hand cannons? If the latter, any specific element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time writing, and to cover all grounds, there are a total of 9 [Hand Cannons](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Hand_Cannons) that have an RPM of 180; 2 of them are acquired via a quest.

**Exotic**

- [Malfeasance](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Malfeasance): Acquired by the quest [Darkness in the Light](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Darkness_in_the_Light)

**Legendary**

- [A Cold Sweat](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/A_Cold_Sweat): Acquired by playing Trials of the Nine
- [IKELOS_HC_v1.0.1](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/IKELOS_HC_v1.0.1): Acquired by the quest [Data Recovery](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Data_Recovery)
- [Nature of the Beast](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Nature_of_the_Beast): Acquired by playing Crucible
- [Optative](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Optative): Rank up reward during Season of the Undying
- [Service Revolver](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Service_Revolver): Acquired by playing Strikes
- [Seventh Seraph Officer Revolver](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Seventh_Seraph_Officer_Revolver): Acquired by Seraph Bounty in Season of the Worthy
- [Trust](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Trust): Acquired by playing Gambit
- [West of Sunfall 7](https://d2.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/West_of_Sunfall_7): Aquired by Brother Vance after fishing Curse of Osris; random chance via Lighthouse Engram on Mercury.